# Error: system.data.dataexception cannot set NAME

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dataview

I have a page with two gridview; one is inside the modal pop up (`grdEmpName`) and the other is in the page (`gvUser`). Now, when the user select search button the modal pop up extender will pop up and then search employees. When the user select someone, the selected data should display to the textbox in the another gridview (`gvUser`).

Everything is working up to selection in modal pop up extender gridview (`grdEmpName`) but when I select no data pass to the other gridview. (`gvUser`). I need to display the selected data in the textbox.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" Width="1024px"
                PageSize="10"  
                AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  
                AllowSorting="true"  
                AllowPaging="true"  
                ShowFooter="True" 
                OnSorting="gvUser_Sorting"  
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvUser_PageIndexChanging"  
                OnRowCreated="gvUser_RowCreated"
                CssClass="Grid"  
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
                FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" > 
                <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" FirstPageImageUrl="~/images/gridview/first_16x16.png" LastPageImageUrl="~/images/gridview/last_16x16.png"  />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField> 
                        <ItemTemplate >      
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_edit_24x24.png"  title = "Edit"  _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Edit|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>'  />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_save_24x24.png" visible="false" title="Update" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Update|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex  & "|-" %>' />  
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_cancel_24x24.png" Visible="false" title="Cancel" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID")& "|Cancel|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>'  /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_delete_24x24.png" title="Delete"  _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID")& "|Delete|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|" & Eval("USR_IDNTY") %>'   /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearchUser" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_search_24x24.png" title="Search" _CommandArgument= "btnSearchUser" OnClick = "btnSearchUser_Click"  /> 
                        </ItemTemplate> 

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/gridview/file_add_24x24.png" title="Add" _CommandArgument='<%# Eval("USR_ID") & "|Add|" &  CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex & "|-" %>' /> 

                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Width="50px"  />            
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Identity" visible ="false" >

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_IDNTY" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USR_IDNTY")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_IDNTY" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("USR_IDNTY")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                 </asp:TemplateField>                        

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" SortExpression="USR_ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSR_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USR_ID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtUSR_ID" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("USR_ID")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>  

                         <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUSR_ID" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>                    

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="NAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNAME" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNAME" runat="server" Width="95%" Text='<%# Bind("NAME")%>'/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNAME" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email"  SortExpression="EMAIL">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEMAIL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EMAIL")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEMAIL" runat="server" Width="95%"  Text='<%# Bind("EMAIL")%>'/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEMAIL" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"  SortExpression="ACTIVE">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkACTIVE"  runat="server" Checked ='<%# Bind("ACTIVE")%>' Enabled="false"   />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkACTIVE" runat="server" Width="95%" Checked ='<%# Bind("ACTIVE")%>'/> 
                        </EditItemTemplate>        

                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkACTIVE" runat="server" Width="95%"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  Wrap="False"/> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                  
                </Columns>
               <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div style="height:315px;border-style:hidden;" >
                        <table class="table" >
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding:5px;" >
                                    <img id="Img1" style="height:24px;width:24px; "  runat="server" src="images/no_data_64x64.png" />    
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding:5px;font-size:large;">
                                     <b>No data found.</b>
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"  />
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyData" />
              </asp:GridView>
          </div>                                        

       <%-- Picker--%>

       <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>


       <cc1:ModalPopupExtender   runat="server" TargetControlID="hdControl" ID="mdlEmpListProcess"  PopupControlID="empPanel" CancelControlID="btnClose"  OnCancelScript="getFlickerSolved();" >
       </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdControl" />
      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="empPanel"  Width="909px" Height="300"  BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderColor="Gray" Style="display:none;" BackColor="Control">

       <table>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtEmpName" CssClass="textbox" Width="240"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearchEmp" CssClass="button" Text="SEARCH" OnClientClick="getFlickerSolved();"/>
                                   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClose" CssClass="button" Text="CLOSE" />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
       </table>   &nbsp;<br />
           &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div style="overflow:scroll; width:882px; height:233px;"> 
                           <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdEmpName"   Width="863px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" Height="35px" GridLines="Vertical">
                                <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="optEmp" AutoPostBack="true" _CommandArgument= "Select" OnCheckedChanged="selectedEmployee" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="USR_ID" HeaderText="USER ID"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME"  HeaderText="NAME"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="EMAIL ADDRESS">  
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>        
                                </Columns>
                               <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
                               <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                               <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                               <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                               <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                               <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                          </asp:GridView>        
         </div>
          </asp:Panel>

         <%-- End Picker--%>
```

Now, here's my code for `selectedEmployee` (Radio Button)

```vb
Public Sub selectedEmployee(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim lnBTNDone As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(lnBTNDone.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    Dim RowIndex As Integer = gvUser.EditIndex
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt = TryCast(Session("dbCache_User"), DataView).Table.Copy
    dt.AcceptChanges()

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt, "", "USR_IDNTY", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
    Dim s As String = TryCast(gvUser.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblUSR_IDNTY"), Label).Text
    Dim idx As Integer = dv.Find(s)

    If idx = -1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Not Found")

    Else

        dv(idx)("USR_ID") = row.Cells(1).Text
        dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text
        dv(idx)("EMAIL") = row.Cells(3).Text

    End If

    gvUser.DataSource = dv
    gvUser.DataBind()

    Me.mdlEmpListProcess.Hide()

End Sub
```

I'm debugging the program to check if value is passing and then when I pass to NAME and Email, I've encounter this error

> system.data.dataexception was unhandled by user code. Cannot set NAME
>   when passing the value.

```vb
dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is virtually impossible to Google for, but try renaming the column NAME to something else. There is a problem in grid views with a column called NAME.

Edits to include a reference to this encouraged.

Comment: which gridview?